# Server cant certificate my website name

Tags: linux, dns, certificate

Hi to first sorry for my English it is bad I have buy a website name he is my 2day ago.

I want to make a site for my company although I don't know anything about it yet ... I have a dedicated server I don't know which cpu 8gb of ram 2terra of disk space, on it I installed webmin plexmediaplayer and bonobox and openvpn. I followed a tutorial

```
apt-get -y install nginx
nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 8;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}

http {

    ##                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    # Basic Settings                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ##                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    # server_name_in_redirect off;                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
```

```
cd /var/www
wget http://fr.wordpress.org/latest-fr_FR.tar.gz
tar -xzvf latest-fr_FR.tar.gz
mv wordpress blog
rm latest-fr_FR.tar.gz
adduser blog
chown -R blog:www-data /var/www/blog
chmod -R o-rwx /var/www/blog
apt-get -y install php-cli php-mysql php-curl php-gd php-intl
php -v
apt-get install -y php-fpm
nano /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/blog.conf
```

```
[blog]
listen = /var/run/blog.sock

listen.owner = blog
listen.group = www-data

user = blog
group = www-data

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s
pm.max_requests = 500
```

```
systemctl stop php7.4-fpm.service
free -m
systemctl start php7.4-fpm.service && ps --no-headers -o "rss,cmd" -C php-fpm7.4 | awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { printf ("%d%s\n", sum/NR/1024,"M") }'
nano /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/blog.conf
```

```
[blog]
listen = /var/run/blog.sock

listen.owner = blog
listen.group = www-data

user = blog
group = www-data

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 263
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s
pm.max_requests = 500
```

```
systemctl restart php7.4-fpm.service
apt-get install -y mariadb-server mariadb-client

mysql_secure_installation
```

```
NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): [Touche Entrée]
OK, successfully used password, moving on...

Setting the root password ensures that nobody can log into the MariaDB
root user without the proper authorisation.

Set root password? [Y/n] Y
New password: 
Re-enter new password: 
Password updated successfully!
Reloading privilege tables..
 ... Success!


By default, a MariaDB installation has an anonymous user, allowing anyone
to log into MariaDB without having to have a user account created for
them.  This is intended only for testing, and to make the installation
go a bit smoother.  You should remove them before moving into a
production environment.

Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] Y
 ... Success!

Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from 'localhost'.  This
ensures that someone cannot guess at the root password from the network.

Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] Y
 ... Success!

By default, MariaDB comes with a database named 'test' that anyone can
access.  This is also intended only for testing, and should be removed
before moving into a production environment.

Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] Y
 - Dropping test database...
 ... Success!
 - Removing privileges on test database...
 ... Success!

Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes made so far
will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] Y
 ... Success!

Cleaning up...

All done!  If you've completed all of the above steps, your MariaDB
installation should now be secure.

Thanks for using MariaDB!
```

```
mysql -u root -p
```

```
CREATE DATABASE blog;
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON blog.* TO '*******'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY  '**********!';
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
MariaDB [(none)]> EXIT;
```

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/blog
```

```
upstream php-wp {
    server            unix:/var/run/blog.sock;
}

server {
    listen            80;
    listen            [::]:80;
    server_name       blog.mondomaine.com;

    root              /var/www/blog;
    
    index             index.php;
    
    location / {
        try_files     $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log    off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow                    all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log    off;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        include       fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  php-wp;
    }

    location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires       max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/blog /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog
systemctl restart nginx.service
apt-get install -y software-properties-common
apt-get install -y certbot
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/blog --agree-tos --no-eff-email --email email@mondomaine.com -d blog.mondomaine.com --rsa-key-size 4096
```

although I'm on debian10. on this one I block in step 9.2 the certificates I have this Domain error message:

```
   www. ********. link
   Type: unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from http: //www.*******.link
   [*************]: "<html xml: lang = \" fr-FR \ "
   lang = \ "fr-FR \"> \ n <head> \ n <title qtlid = \ "28806 \"> Congratulations!
   Your domain has been successfully created at OVH! </ "

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A / AAAA record (s) for that domain
   contain (s) the right IP address.
```

and on the other I am at the stage where I have to access wordpress installed on the site ...

but i'm still redirected to ovh so i decided to look on the hosting side of my site and i found this  i block at l 'step 2.3.2 then when I do the 2.3.3 I have this error message during the following command

```
% named-checkconf
-bash: fg:%: no such job
```

here my configuration of named.conf from bind

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
server **********
server 127.0.0.1
server ************ {


zone "********.link" {
        type master;
        file "*********.zone";
```

I do this:

```
           apt-get install bind9
           cd  /etc/bind/
           nano named.conf
```

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    forwarders {
        ***********;
        ***********;
     };

    auth-nxdomain no;
};
```

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

```
search liste_de_domaines_pour_les_noms_DNS_dont_le_domaine_n'est_pas_précisé
nameserver127.0.0.1
nameserver **********
nameserver **********
```

```
nano named.conf
```

```
zone "*******" {
    type master;
    file "*********.zone";
};
```

```
cp ~/config/*********.zone /var/cache/bind/
% named-checkconf
```

EDIT: I understand now I have asked a second ip for my server, I come back soon to tell you more!
thank you for the layout!!!!!
Can you help me please ????
many thanks
Sam

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Couple of points - You're pretty much dumped out your whole  config file with  no real context. Your actual problem is right at the end, and its unclear where you're seeing it.  You're talking about being blocked at specific steps - with no link to the guide.

Comment: Also, rather than some random guide on the internet - use [certbot's docs](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions) for setting up certbot, and [ssl-config.mozilla.org](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org) for nginx config. Its fairly intuitive and up to date, and will save you many headaches in the process.

Comment: Another question is your configuration is on port 80 - can you access the blog over HTTP?

Comment: Hi thank you for rreponses! i wll give the link her ti moringand i Wil take  l n the sitye ou recommande m thans
I dont kow if thiss on port 80 i wil che"ck this andald soo
han yu l eszt regard
and naturlly next time i will take a look on nth for0um how forat

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need a second IP address. Using name-based virtual hosting, you can have *any number* of domains on a single IP address. The response `certbot` lists indicates the domain you acquired is not pointing at your server:

```
Detail: Invalid response from http: //www.*******.link
   [*************]: "<html xml: lang = \" fr-FR \ "
   lang = \ "fr-FR \"> \ n <head> \ n <title qtlid = \ "28806 \"> Congratulations!
   Your domain has been successfully created at OVH! </ "
```

This is not a response your server would return. It is the OVH domain parking page.

You must go to the OVH domain control panel and change the domain’s A record to your server’s IP address.

You do not need to set up a DNS server yourself. [DNS is already included.](https://www.ovh.com/world/domains/dns_management_service.xml)

---

May I also recommend managed hosting? Securing and managing a dedicated server requires advanced Linux and network knowledge. The work never ends, either. Updates become available, new vulnerabilities are discovered…

If you want to learn, a cheap VPS may be a better solution. Take it slow, starting with Linux basics, security (stuff like firewalls, securing SSH, …) and then maybe some *static* (think HTML files) web hosting. Once that works you can continue with Let’s Encrypt (with `certbot` or otherwise) to get HTTPS up and running. Or maybe dynamic sites using PHP.

I believe it is very important to know how things are set up and how they interact.

Comment: Hi thank you for helping me! i have cancelled the 2e ip adresss.and change the ip adress of my name domaine but now he link of my bonobox XD  i have a server with debian and one vps for my test i will learn a little bit more.
thank you @Daniel B